# Windows Xp stop error

Tags: windows-xp

I bought a Thikpad T410 its Core i5 proccesor
4Gb Ram
160Gb hard Disk
I wanted to downgrade Win7 to XP
But while installation this error occoured
0x0000007B (0xF78D2524, 0xc0000034, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
I know its an INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE error
But why is this happening
is the Notebook protecting itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the steps listed here, it's a common issue. The PC can't talk to its hard drive basically. Could be several causes.

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/stop0x0000007b.htm

Comment: Tnx it was Bios setting error